# Type of convergence of $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \int \frac{s^{\alpha}}{s - z} ds$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to prove that the Cauchy transform  of $s^{\alpha}$ grows as $z^{\alpha}$ when approaching $0$ if $-1 < \alpha < 0$ or in other words $\int_0^1 \frac{s^{\alpha}}{s - z} ds = \mathcal{O} \left( z^{\alpha} \right) $ at $z \to 0$ when $-1 < \alpha < 0$.

I have an intuitive proof:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{s^{\alpha}}{s - z} ds
\approx \int_{-z}^{1-z} \frac{(t + z)^{\alpha}}{t} ds
\approx \int_{-z}^{1-z} \frac{t^{\alpha}}{t} ds
\approx -\frac{(-z)^{\alpha}}{\alpha} + \frac{(1-z)^{\alpha}}{\alpha}
\end{align}
and this is clearly $\mathcal{O} \left( z^{\alpha} \right) $ at $z \to 0$. However, $z$ is complex, the approximation signs are not sufficient and the second step uses convergence of integrals while this is not shown.

Does anybody have any idea how to prove this properly?

Comment: How do you know that $(1-z)^\alpha = O(z^\alpha)$ ? This is not necessarily the case

Comment: No, $(1 - z)^{\alpha}$ is O(1), because $\alpha \neq 0$, so that part is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ninad Munshi original answer to my question that was badly formulated I managed to come up with an argument that is at least to me compelling enough to show that this holds.
It is basically the following string of inequalities.
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \left\lvert \int\limits_0^{1} \frac{s^{\alpha}}{s - z} ds
\right\rvert
&= \lim\limits_{z \to 0} \left\lvert z^{\alpha} \int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{z}} \frac{t^{\alpha}}{t - \frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert}} dt \right\rvert \\
        &= \lim\limits_{z \to 0} \lvert z \rvert^{\alpha} (\lvert z \rvert^{-\alpha} - C_3) \\
        &= \lim\limits_{z \to 0} (1 - C_3  \lvert z \rvert^{\alpha})
        = O(\lvert z \rvert^{\alpha})
\end{align*}
I used that $\frac{1}{{t - \frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert}}}$ does not diverge at 0 and that $\frac{t^{\alpha}}{{t - \frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert}}} \to t^{\alpha - 1}$ as $t \to \infty$ as $z \to 0$ which will dominate the integral. Note, that $\frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert}$ is either negative or complex with modulus 1 (so not in $[0, +\infty)$ the integral does not diverges in $[0, +\infty)$.